# Adding UIWindow removes status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding a subvview on top of the status bar. First I'm creating a new window:

```
let currentWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

currentWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
```

Next I add the subview:

```
currentWindow?.addSubview(self.profileView!)
```

The problem I'm having is that when I remove the subview, the status bar does not show any more throughout the application. Am I supposed to remove `currentWindow` as well?

Comment: Show a bit more code like where you create your second window and how you remove your second window. And perhaps a screenshot of what you want it look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove your subview, you'll need to set `windowLevel` back to its default value so that the status bar is visible again.

```
let currentWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
currentWindow!.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
```